# Пропускается часть пути при использовании app_dev.php в Symfony 3.3

Tags: маршрутизация, symfony3, инструменты-разработчика

Имеется BlogBundle, в котором routing задан BlogBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml:

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Blog:homepage  }
blog_view:
    path:     /blog/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Blog:blogView }
    requirements:
            page: '\d+'
```

Также имеется главный app\config\routing.yml:

```
blog:
    resource: '@BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
```

И app\config\routing_dev.yml:

```
_wdt:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
    prefix: /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
    prefix: /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: '@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    prefix: /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Когда я проверяю symfony3/blog/3, то всё получается без проблем, но когда ввожу symfony3/app_dev.php/blog/3, возвращается ошибка "No route found for "GET g"".
В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в файл-конфигураторе .htaccess. После того, как его удалил - всё заработало.

Comment: А что было в `.htaccess`?